# Equidistant Points in Wrapping Rectangle

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble figuring out the math for a problem I am having.

I have an n by m rectangle and need to place k points in it such that points are, as close as possible, completely equidistant from each other.

Normally this is pretty easy, I construct the regular polygon with k points on it, center it in the center of my rectangle, stretch it to fit and voila, its vertices are my output points.

The catch is that when calculating distances on this rectangle, you can wrap. As such the point (0,0) is just 1 pixel away from the point (n-1,m-1) (using 0-indexed coordinates).

I've been messing around a bit on paper and getting nowhere fast with this. Does anybody have any idea how to calculate this?

tl;dr:

Inputs: n - width of rectangle, m - height of rectangle, k - number of points
Outputs: k pairs of (x,y) coordinates
Constraints: the output coordinates are equidistant from one another under wrapping coordinate systems.

Any advice on where I could look for such a geometry problem?

Comment: See where a re-conceptualization brings you: you aren't dealing with a rectangle, you are dealing with a torus. Another visualisation for the problem: repeat your rectangle (seen as a tile) when you draw in one tile you draw in all of them -  see how the distances play out when considering the neighbour tiles. Another issue here: what distance do you use? Manhattan dist (L1) or Euclid (L2)

Comment: I'm using manhattan distance, but both are actually acceptable in this instance. I've tried visualizing as a torus and as an infinite plane, the best I came up with is a system that is "fair" but not "equidistant" (involves creating a ?x? grid of points that has spacing that is relatively prime to the rectangle size, then resolving the coordinates from the much larger placement grid down to the smaller grid).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the points being equidistant from each other? In the example with the regular polygon, each point will only be equidistant from the 2 neighbouring points on the polygon, not from all the other points. Is it the criteria the same in the wrapping case?

Comment: Well that's exactly the issue. The more equidistant the better. This is for a game I am making where each team starts with 'k' units. Positioning is extremely important, but the playing field is a wrapping rectangle as described. There could be anywhere from 1 to 7 players and each could start with any number of units. Right now I randomly place them, but sometimes it leads to very unfair games.